# Lighttpd and WebDAV for serving a Subversion repo

Tags: svn, webdav, lighttpd

I've configured (at least I've tried to configure) Lighty to enable the WebDAV plugin when I go to a certain URL. I don't get any errors, so it seems to be working. How, then, do I configure it to serve my subversion repositories (of which I have many)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible right now, since mod_dav_svn is an apache module and AFAIK there is no lighttpd module available.